# Why did the CSS colour for quotations change?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

It used to be a yellow background that easily stands out.  Now it looks like this.

[image]

IMO, it doesn't stand out at all.  There's not even a background colour, and the left side grey border is easy to miss.

Can we change it back, or is it out of our hands?

Comment: Agreed, this new style is super ugly...

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394516/2075105 My understanding is that visual changes to the SE are now network-wide, and by design they don't intend to allow changes like this on a per-site basis.  I'll leave this question unanswered, though, so SE can pop in and give an official response if they like.

Comment: The request to change this back has been filed here https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344874/299332

Comment: @Earthliŋ:  Thank you

Comment: I personally prefer the current style. Some users were using quotations just as a yellow box to emphasize an important part of their answer, which was confusing to me. I do not see why a quote has to be in a yellow box.

Comment: I prefer the yellow style. To me it's a useful tool for visual delineation and it can help make an answer more readable. Its original purpose might be for quotations but I don't think it should be limited to that purpose.

Comment: @Flaw well, except those who use screen reader might be fooled if it is actually a real quotation or not...

Comment: @naruto Right -- this style is more useful to indicate a real quote, but in reality what most people want is the emphasis / 'extra content' / hierarchy effect that the more visually distinct yellow box had, whether it's a quote or not.

Comment: (BTW, just a note that I think calling it 'ugly' probably isn't helpful and might be a little offensive to the UI folks that made the change. Saying how/why it doesn't meet your needs precisely is both kinder and I think more effective. :)

Comment: Actually, it seems that most of the discussion about the change is on the original announcement: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/299332

Answer (score 1):

For those of you as annoyed with this change as I am, here's a script I cobbled together for [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), that puts things back to the original look.

Note that I'm no expert with javascript/CSS so this might be a really dumb way to do things, but it works for me.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     SEblockquote
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @include https://japanese.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];    
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}

addGlobalStyle('blockquote { background-color: #fbf2d4 !important; }');
addGlobalStyle('blockquote::before { width: 0px !important; }');
```

Comment: Good call with greasemonkey.  Didn't even think about that.

Comment: What bothers me most about the change is that *other* people don't get the benefit of my answer layout, so this doesn't help me that much... (thank you though!!)

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Yes, that bothers me too. Sadly, I don't have a solution. Inserting your own html doesn't seem to work as the engine ignores most html tags and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a greasemonkey/tampermonkey script that styles it more in-line with the site's own style.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Japanese StackExchange (and meta) Blockquote
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @include https://japanese.stackexchange.com/*
// @include https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}

addGlobalStyle('blockquote { background-color: #F0F1F4 !important; background-image: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/japanese/img/site-background-image.svg?v=3e09a9473831") !important; border-left-width: 4px; border-left-color: #155397; border-left-style: solid; }');
addGlobalStyle('blockquote::before { width: 0px !important; }');
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]